# IOS Safari URL UTI share sheet

Tags: ios, swift, url, share, photo

I am trying to pass the current URL from safari to my app using the safari share button and share sheet.  I want this to go to my app and not have it be a share extension. From safari, the share sheet does not show my app.  I have registered the following document types (UTI) without success:

```
public.url  
public.file-url 
public.url-name
```

My app does show up from a pdf document share using com.adobe.pdf without any issues.  Any help sharing the URL from safari would be most appreciated. I am also having a similar issue with using share button from a photo displayed from the apple app.

What are the correct UTI for safari url and a photo via the share button to properly appear on the share sheet?  Thanks.

Bob

Comment: Your app won't show on the Share sheet by default. Did you swipe right and tap on `More...` to activate your app?

Comment: Yes - I looked for it there.  It was not listed.

Answer (score 1):

- Go to the project (root element in the Project Navigator) and select your Share target
- Go to Info
- Open `NSEXtension` -> `NSExtensionAttributes` -> `NSExtensionActivationRule`
- For URL Support: Add `NSExtensionActivationSupportsWebURLWithMaxCount` underneath `NSExtensionActivationRule` (type is `Number`, the value is any number higher than 0 depending how many URL's you allow to handle in one share action)
- For Photo and/or Video Support add `NSExtensionActivationSupportsImageWithMaxCount` and/or `NSExtensionActivationSupportsMovieWithMaxCount`
- For other file types add `NSExtensionActivationSupportsFileWithMaxCount`

In the raw code of the Info.plist file of your Share target it will look like this:

```
<key>NSExtension</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSExtensionAttributes</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSExtensionActivationRule</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSExtensionActivationSupportsFileWithMaxCount</key>
            <integer>10</integer>
            <key>NSExtensionActivationSupportsImageWithMaxCount</key>
            <integer>10</integer>
            <key>NSExtensionActivationSupportsMovieWithMaxCount</key>
            <integer>10</integer>
            <key>NSExtensionActivationSupportsWebURLWithMaxCount</key>
            <integer>1</integer>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    <key>NSExtensionMainStoryboard</key>
    <string>YourStoryboard</string>
    <key>NSExtensionPointIdentifier</key>
    <string>com.apple.share-services</string>
</dict>
```

NOTE for people who don't see their app appearing in Dropbox'es Export sheet: Dropbox passes a URL to the share sheet, you'd have to support `NSExtensionActivationSupportsWebURLWithMaxCount`

Comment: I'd like some more information on how to actually open the app with the URL once this is registered in the action extension.

Comment: What if we want the app (not a extension) to handle them?

Answer (score 0):

I just dealt w/ this issue.  It appears to be a Safari issue and not an App configuration issue.  So long as your permissions are set correctly per the documentation, try testing in google chrome.  Shares just fine from there...